# Orthogonal ("Hodge") Decomposition of $L^2(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ being unbounded

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

In *Mathematical Analysis and Numerical Methods for Science and Technology: Volume 3 Spectral Theory and Applications* it is stated on page 313 that for a regular and bounded set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ several decomposition for $L^2(\Omega)^n$ apply, such as
$$L^2(\Omega)^n=\rm{grad}\,H_0^1(\Omega)\oplus H(\rm{div}\,0,\Omega).$$
A footnote present on the same page states that in the case where $\Omega$ is the complement of a bounded set, there exist analogous equalities which result by replacing the Sobolev spaces with certain Beppo Levi spaces. Is someone aware of a resource which states this result in a more explicit way?

Answer (score 1):

These spaces are also called [Deny-Lions Spaces](https://doi.org/10.5802/aif.55) in that case, but that book was co-authored by Lions so he did not name it that way.

An example of such use is [here](http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_1971__46__227_0/).

I think the main reference is  [Amrouche Girault and Giroire](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-7824(97)89945-X),  and if you look at the [google scholar citation of that paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=511054492515558559) you will find a number of articles where this approach is developed.

The general idea is to map back from outside to inside, and then apply the results of [Girault and Raviart](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2765609559343690579) for example (or others).